# is it possible to use 'put on' with emotion?

Tags: idioms

I saw the phrase

> put on air of happiness

as the meaning is 'to pretend to be happy', 
if i say

> 'put on happiness'

does it mean 'to be happy'? or is it nonsense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the phrase

> put on

you need to be a little bit careful. It has the literal meaning of "to wear"

> put on a happy face
>   *wear a happy face*

but it also has the meaning to be sarcastic (to not actually mean what one is saying)

> Stop putting me on!

Your first sentence would be better written as

> Put on **a** happy face *(needs the article a)*

your second sentence

> put on happiness

has a different meaning, which is to place "happiness" on *something*

> I put on happiness
>   I put on my shirt

it doesn't really have any meaning, but most native speaker will surmise what you are saying.